# html file browsing in java swing

Tags: java, swing, html-parsing

I am displaying Html file data in Java swing form . the contents are displaying but some formatting is disturbed . Images are being displayed but formatting is disturbed . 
and hyperlinks  are not working  can you suggest me the code ,I am using following code .
Is something wrong with setContentType method

```
    File htmlFile = new File("e:/test/help4t.htm");
             htmlPane = new JEditorPane();
            htmlPane.setContentType("text/html");
        htmlPane.setPage(htmlFile.toURI().toURL());
         //URL url= new URL("http://www.lawcrux.com");


       //  htmlPane.setPage(url);
         htmlPane.addHyperlinkListener(this);

        JScrollPane jsp= new JScrollPane(htmlPane);

                cp.add(jsp);
        jsp.setBounds(750, 50, 600, 600);  


        } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "exception is" + ex);
        }
```

please help

regards

Comment: Is it the (garish) `http://www.lawcrux.com/` or a HTML on local disk that you control, or something else, that you wish to display to the end user?  `JEditorPane` will never render the JS based scrolling text/links part of that page (fortunately) or the JS based calendar.

Comment: The Html file is stored on the local system . Is there another way to render the JS based links and text

Comment: I think JavaFX is supposed to offer a web component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `Jsoup` for it provides  a very convenient API for **extracting and manipulating data.**

**See this link:**

http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 3):

Okay well `JEditorPane` only supports up to HTML 3.2.

Even with the above said; I would not recoommend rendering html using no library (or your own - unless thats your project) to help you. Have a look at (pure Java libraries):

- [The Lobo Project](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/getting-started.jsp) (The Lobo Project aims to develop an extensible browser and RIA platform written completely in Java that not only supports HTML and Javascript, but also enables rendering of arbitrary Rich Internet Application (RIA) languages)
- [Ekit](http://www.hexidec.com/ekit.php) (Ekit is a free open source Java HTML editor applet and application. The Ekit standalone also allows for HTML to be loaded and saved, as well as serialized and saved as an RTF. It is approaching its first production release version.)
- [The DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html) (The NativeSwing library allows an easy integration of some native components into Swing applications, and provides some native utilities to enhance Swing's APIs. It is composed of a framework library, and an SWT-based implementation that provides many rich components.
  The key components of this SWT-based implementation are of course a rich Web Browser and a Flash player, though it also offers a Multimedia Player, an HTML Editor and a Syntax Highlighter.)
- [CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/) (CSSBox is an (X)HTML/CSS rendering engine written in pure Java. Its primary purpose is to provide a complete and further processable information about the rendered page contents and layout. However, it also allows displaying the rendered document.)
- [RealObjects](http://www.realobjects.com/products/project-martha/) (not free though)